# Unable to use jQuery to select Angular Dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have this angular component on the page which has all the options binded.

Using jQuery, I was able to retrieve the correct selected value with the following:

```
 $('#mat-select').val(); // returns me the id of the selected option
```

However, when I try to update the value with jQuery, the value is updated but not reflected on the component on the screen.

eg.

```
 $('#mat-select').val(); // eg. returns 'mat-select-option-0'
 $('#mat-select').val('mat-select-option-5').trigger('input').trigger('change');
 $('#mat-select').val(); // returns me 'mat-select-option-5'
```

Yet, the selected value on the component still appears to be `mat-select-option-0`. I am guessing that I am just setting the dom's `value` attribute and not updating the angular component but couldn't figure out how.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recomended to use jQuery together with Angular, because they bouth are manipulating with dom in their own way try using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

That will allow you to avoid many future problems.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am trying to do some jquery plugin to help me fill up some forms. i am not trying to make changes to the site directly. any suggestions on how to go about?